# Default image of App in Google Play is not shown while sharing using google PlusShare

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-one

When users tap G+ in the android App, It should fetch the image as shown in the document for PLUS SHARE. But it is not showing any image of my App. 
[image]

[image]

Could you please let me know what fix is needed in my code

### String value

```
<string name="plus_example_deep_link_id">
    https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.egg.catcher.fun</string>
<string name="plus_example_deep_link_url">
    https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.egg.catcher.fun
</string>
```

### Code

```
    private Intent getInteractivePostIntent() {
    // Create an interactive post with the "VIEW_ITEM" label. This will
    // create an enhanced share dialog when the post is shared on Google+.
    // When the user clicks on the deep link, ParseDeepLinkActivity will
    // immediately parse the deep link, and route to the appropriate  
   resource.
    String action = "/?view=true";
/*
    Uri callToActionUrl = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_url) + action);
    String callToActionDeepLinkId = getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_id) + action;
*/

    Uri callToActionUrl = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_url));
    String callToActionDeepLinkId = getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_id);

    // Create an interactive post builder.
    PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(this);

    // Set call-to-action metadata.
    builder.addCallToAction(LABEL_VIEW_ITEM, callToActionUrl, callToActionDeepLinkId);

    // Set the target url (for desktop use).
    builder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_url)));

    // Set the target deep-link ID (for mobile use).
    builder.setContentDeepLinkId(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_id),
            null, null, null);

    // Set the pre-filled message.
    builder.setText(mEditSendText.getText().toString());

    return builder.getIntent();
}
```

Comment: Is it not showing the thumbnail only for preview? Or is the thumbnail also not showing for shared posts?

Comment: While creating the post I am not seeing any thumbnail. After I have shared the post, the post has the thumbnail of the App

Comment: It's possible that G+ has changed the sharing UI to not show an image in this circumstance.

Comment: I have a similar issue in facebook shares of my google play link

Comment: In facebook, Dont use ShareLinkContent. Better use the Open graph